# SQL To Find Word Pairs/Clusters Between Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, text, data-mining

I have a SQL Server 2012 database with a table that contains questions and answers. Simplified structure is like this:

```
question_id  int 
question   varchar(500)
answer     varchar(50)
```

I'd like to find word pairs or clusters between the question and answer columns. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this in SQL as opposed to R, etc. I've seen a lot of stuff on document clustering, but I'm wondering where to start just in the db itself at the column level.

So, for example, I want to find the answer to this question: when the question column contains word X, how often is it paired with word Y in the answer column?

Comment: Just extracting words from a string is a pain in SQL.  I would suggest you use another tool for this.  If you are intent on using SQL, it would help if you have a table of valid words in the `question` and `answer` columns.

Comment: SQL Server comes with full text indexing.  Great for finding a key word in a help desk ticket.  However, what you asking is a correlation of words in the question column to the answer column. This sounds like a C# console program to store valid question/answer words being stored as keys (one table) and a key/pair of every combo (another table).  Then some analysis after you have the data.

Comment: r u looking for this "where question like '%X%' and answer like '%Y%'"

Comment: @KumarHarsh No, the idea is that I don't know what X and Y are beforehand. I need to discover the relationships/patterns. So, it looks like there is no straightforward way to do this in SQL alone. I'm assuming this could be done in SSAS using MDX or in Python/R, but I don't really know where to begin as far as the model or algorithms. Thanks.

Comment: Does SQL server also support stemming and full-text *joins*? Usually, text search functionality in SQL databases is existant, but largely useless for data mining because it doesn't scale good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of problems, I recommend looking at the **word count map-reduce example**.

Some SQL servers by now allow you to execute map-reduce like functions on their tables, and can then optimize this reasonably well. Note that the *iterim data* can still become *really* large, so you may need to A) use clever hashing techniques (think of bloom filters) to avoid materializing the initial join at all, or B) maybe actually load the data into a Hadoop cluster and process it there. MapReduce is well capable of scaling this problem to huge data sets (think: all of Wikipedia)

Either way, I don't think SQL will make you happy. String manipulation in SQL is a *pain*. See e.g. the following related questions:

[How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql)

[T-SQL: Opposite to string concatenation - how to split string into multiple records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco)

You first need to implement tokenizing/splitting and stemming, stopword removal, and then perform a `JOIN` on the tokens from question and answer, and then do this for all questions and count the most common pairs.